# Failed to pass arguments to chrome driver in selenium

Tags: python, linux, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-extension

I use selenium to test my chrome extension, and I recently found the Travis-CI  reported a failing status.

[image: travis-ci screenshot]

I reproduced the problem and realized chrome didn't even load my extension.

Here is a short example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

opt=Options()
opt.add_argument('load-extension=/path/to/src')
opt.add_argument('--user-agent=foobar')

b=webdriver.Chrome('driver/chromedriver',chrome_options=opt)
print(b.execute_script('return navigator.userAgent'))
```

The chrome launched without the extension loaded, and the user agent string was still the default one (`Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.75 Safari/537.36`).

The chrome driver I'm using is [v2.33](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.33/chromedriver_linux64.zip) with [google-chrome-stable (62.0.3202.75-1)](http://dl.google.com/dl/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb). The OS is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (this bug is not reproduceable in Windows).

I'm wondering is it a bug in a recent update in chrome or selenium, as the code was working 3 days ago.

Is there any workaround for this bug?

(sorry for my poor English)

Answer (score 2):

Comparing 2 build outputs, the version of selenium changed from 3.6.0 to 3.7.0.

[image]

Downgrading selenium to `selenium==3.6.0` will fix the problem.

Comment: This fixed the issue of passing in options to Chrome, but my selenium code still stalls after loading the browser.